# Memsql deploys clusters on multiple hosts that cannot be installed and memsql_id files are missing

Tags: singlestore

error:
Failed to install MemSQL: Could not retrieve MemSQL ID: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/memsql/leaf-3306-1/data/memsql_id'

I would appreciate it if you could work it out

Comment: Was this during an install? Can you dump the logs to pastebin or something as well as your conf file?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer .During the installation process, memsql_id should be similar to a secret key, each node of the secret key is different, but now ,this file cannot be generated